# Is there a possibility to create a const value with non const functions?

Tags: rust, fonts

In my code I want to load the raw data of a font installed on my Linux. For this I took the crate [font-loader](https://crates.io/crates/font-loader). Up this point there is no issue. But this crate gives me the raw data as `Vec<u8>`.

This font should then be used by the graphics library [embedded-graphics](https://crates.io/crates/embedded-graphics), where I took [u8g2-fonts](https://crates.io/crates/u8g2-fonts) as a way to handle different fonts.

But for this to work I have to implement `Font` for a custom `struct`:

```rust
pub struct libertation_font;
impl Font for libertation_font {
    const DATA: &'static [u8] = todo!();
}
```

Coming to my question. Is it possible to load the font with font-loader and implement the `Font` trait where the data is what I got from font-loader? Or is this impossible due to the way Rust handles `const`?

Comment: An even better place to ask this would probably be https://github.com/matprec/rust-font-loader/issues, as that sounds like a pretty common use-case for a font loaded using that library. Worst case they'd go "I don't know" and then SO is the right place to ask, but best case they go "oh hey yeah let me add a bit to the library to make that easier".

Comment: That's a nice idea. Should be helpful for other people as well imho

Answer (score 2):

No. `const` values must be evaluateable at compile time. That means they must be initialized by a `const` function. You could also try using [`include_bytes!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes.html) macro and/or writing a build script that at **compile time** will load fonts and include them in the binary. But you cannot do that at runtime.